# select N items from DB but display only k (where k<N) in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following code where I am selecting 100 items from the db, but would like to display only 5 in the dropdown. The .Take method does not seem to work.

```
   HeatService heatService = new HeatService();
        List<HeatDropdownOption> availableHeats = heatService.GetHeats()
                                               .Where(h => h.ComponentType.Equals(componentType.ToString()))
                                               .OrderByDescending(h => h.Date)
                                               .Take(Constants.NMostRecentHeats)
                                               .Select(h => new HeatDropdownOption(h))
                                               .ToList();

        //HeatDropdown = new MultiSelectList(availableHeats, "ID", "Label", selectedHeats.Select(h=>h.ID).ToList());
        HeatDropdown = new MultiSelectList(availableHeats, "ID", "Label", selectedHeats.Take(5).Select(h => h.ID).ToList());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you look at the overloads of `MultiSelectList` the `4th overload` is to select items in the list and the `1st overload` is to set the data to dropdown so we can use `.Take(5)` to filter the data before populating it in the `dropdown`. so if you want to display only 5 in `dropdown` use take like this

```
    HeatDropdown = new MultiSelectList(availableHeats.Take(5), "ID", "Label");
```

it will display the first 5 items from the `availableHeats`

Comment: But that does not let me search through all the items retrieved from the database.